# Prove non-zero eigenvalues of $A\Sigma A'$ and $A'A\Sigma$ are equal

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let
$$
    A = \begin{bmatrix}
    1&1&1&1\\
    1&1&0&0\\
    0&0&1&1\\
    1&0&0&0\\
    0&1&0&0\\
    0&0&1&0\\
    0&0&0&1
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
is $7 \times 4$ matrix of full column rank. For a positive definite 
matrix $\Sigma$, how can we prove that non zero eigenvalues of $A\Sigma A'$ and
$A'A\Sigma$ are equal.

Note: $A'$ is the transpose of matrix $A$.

Comment: What dou you mean equal? The first matrix is $7\times 7$, the second matrix is $4\times 4$.

Comment: AΣA′ is singular. Hence three of its eigenvalues are zero. Need to prove that non-zero eigenvalues of AΣA′ and A′AΣ are equal.

Comment: That's not what you said in the question. Please edit it to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true for the nonzero eigenvalues:

Suppose first that $u \in \mathbb{R}^7$ is an eigenvector of $A\Sigma A'$ with eigenvalue $\lambda \neq 0$. Then $A'u \neq 0$ is an eigenvector of $A'A\Sigma$ with eigenvalue $\lambda$:
$$ A'A\Sigma (A'u) = A'(A\Sigma A')u = A'(\lambda u) = \lambda (A'u). $$
On the other hand, suppose that $v \in \mathbb{R}^4$ is an eigenvector of $A'A\Sigma$ with eigenvalue $\mu$. Then
$$ A\Sigma A'(A\Sigma v) = A\Sigma (A'A\Sigma v) = A\Sigma (\mu v) = \mu(A\Sigma v), $$
so provided that $A\Sigma v \neq 0$, it is an eigenvector of $A\Sigma A'$ with eigenvalue $\mu$. This follows because $\Sigma$ is positive-definite so has full rank, and $A$ has full rank, so each is injective onto its image.

---

However, $\ker{A'}$ is three-dimensional, so $A\Sigma A'$ also has $0$ as an eigenvalue, with three-dimensional eigenspace given by $\ker{A'}$.

Comment: Is it that $A\Sigma\nu$ is an eigenvector of $A \Sigma A'$ with eigenvalue $\mu$, not $\lambda$? I didn't get what you mean by there is an extra eigenvalue zero? Could you please explain a bit.

Comment: If $u \in \ker{A'}$, $A'u=0$, so $A\Sigma A' u=0$ and $u$ is an eigenvector of $A\Sigma A'$ with eigenvalue 0.

Comment: Thanks for helping out with this!

Comment: Can you please explain me how the ranks of $A$ and $\Sigma$ are useful in here?